# IIS localhost is redirecting to the live server instead of showing local aspx files

Tags: asp.net, iis, localhost

I need to redesign a site front-end to make it responsive, the site is based on C# and ASPX. I am familiar with working PHP local development environment by using WAMP so for this case I installed visualstudio web express because of its IIS server features for testing local development.

The client sent the folder from its ftp for me to work on so I have everything ready but the problem which I am facing is that when I try to right-click on the website folder from the solution explorer to view in the browser the localhost is redirecting to the actual live site which is running on the server instead of taking me to the localhost with local files so that I can have a view of my modification and changes.

I am unable to figuring out the problem may be there is something I need to change or replace in the webconfig file. I am working in asp environment for the first time your help and guidance in this regard will be very appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: Then you'll need to find where it's redirecting.

Comment: @CodeCaster it is redirecting me to the website that I need to modify, i.e, I have a task to redesign the www.abc123.com I have a local folder for abc123 which is referenced in visualstudio solution explorer and when I want see the preview and abc123 is not showing in localhost, the browser is taking me to the acutal www.abc123.com

Comment: Yeah I understand. That's probably because the code of the website itself does something like that. Try to search the files for the URL of the site so you can see where that happens.

Comment: Take a look at Default.aspx or Globla.asax's code behind

Comment: @CodeCaster I searched for the url in the find window I found lots of it but I found it also in webconfig where the rewrite rules are written and it is described there even I have commented it for no use and it is still redirecting to the real-time site

Comment: @Oscar I have gone through the Default.aspx there is nothing relevant instead of plain html tags with texts on it and some serverside c# tags but there is not url or something like that mentioned at there

Comment: @Lightcoder In Asp.Net usually you have two files with the same name: one with aspx extension and another with cs extension. Inside aspx file you have the markup, but the code (usually) goes inside the one with the cs extension.

Answer (score 5):

I had this same problem just now as well as two or three times before and haven't pinned down a clear cut resolution, though I've tried removing redirects, checking the Global.asax, commenting out default document files in the Web.config, etc. I'm mainly working in Chrome on Windows 7, and after I cleared Chrome's cache localhost started working for me again. I don't know if the answer is as simple as that or if the solution comes from some combination of things. All I know is nothing else seemed to work, then clearing the browser cache did.

Comment: You are absolutely right regarding clearing the browser cache. I have also commented out the redirection instructions in the web.config and now when I go for the preview at first time the localhost appears with the changes I made and when I go another time for the preview and the browser redirects to the original live version of site. I am still stuck :)

Answer (score 1):

**PROBLEM**

I was facing this problem because I wrote this rule inside **webconfig** file.

```
 <rules>
  <rule name="CanonicalHostNameRule1">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.abc\.com$" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="www.abc.com/{R:1}" />
  </rule>
</rules>
```

And because of this when I debug the solution the localhost is replaced with **www.abc.com**

**SOLUTION**

Just remove this rule if written

**WHY USE RULE**

These rules are used when you want to customize the url ,you can read further about Url Rewrite [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module)

Comment: to check the existence of such rule is the first choice. after removing the rule you need to clear the browser cache also. After that, all went fine with local host like expected.

Answer (score 0):

Redirecting to the live site from visual studio or localhost can be caused by a faulty url rewrite rule in the site web config. Even if the rule is deleted, the browser may cache the rule if it is a permanent redirect, and therefore clearing the browser cache and fixing the faulty rule can be a viable solution.

See article
https://theludditedeveloper.wordpress.com/2016/01/06/iis-url-rewrite-gotcha-2/

Answer (score 0):

For me it was because the web.config had a rewrite rule added in it for SSL purpose. However, once I removed it, it still kept me redirecting to the live site. I wasted couple of hours searching the code without anything making sense. And then it turned out that the cache was the issue as the browser was still doing the redirection. So, I cleared the cache and it was solved.